# How best to add records to TArray

Tags: delphi

While coding a test program I ran across this sample code:

```
var MyData: TArray<TDataRec>;

procedure AppendData(AItem: TOrderByCustomer);
var i: Integer;
  tmp: TArray<TOrderByCustomer>;
begin
  SetLength(tmp, Length(MyData)+1);
  for i:=0 to High(MyData) do
    tmp[i]:=MyData[i];

  tmp[Length(tmp)-1]:=AItem;
  MyData:=tmp;
end;
```

In the past I have simply used SetLength() to change the length of the actual array. Why did the author of this sample create a temporary array and then assign all of the values to it and copy it back to the original array? Is there a good reason for this, or was he just being weird?

Comment: He's been weird.

Comment: Indeed, the author may not know how these things actually work.

Comment: If you are adding a lot of items to an array, you should a more flexible container instead, like `TList<T>`.

Comment: FWIW, this is not going to work, unless TDataRec and TOrderByCustomer are of the same type. I assume this was a fabricated example, and not the real code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no good reason for this code. It introduces the potential overhead of needless copying. The function should be written like this:

```
procedure AppendData(const AItem: TOrderByCustomer);
var
  N: Integer;
begin
  N := Length(MyData);
  SetLength(MyData, N + 1);
  MyData[N] := AItem;
end;
```

Comment: Also  `MyData := MyData + [AItem];` or `Insert`  since XE7

Comment: One note: if you do this repeatedly and with many values, you risk memory fragmentation and a constant slowdown. If possible, add to the length in larger chunks and keep track of how many of the elements are valid. See my blog: http://rvelthuis.blogspot.com/2004/